# Visual Basic 2010 Zooming

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, zooming, graphing

So I've created a graphing calculator style program to display vector lines and their resultant after addition.

My question is: for lines of greater size than the window size I have designated for display, how can I "zoom" in or out of that window with in the page. I have tried doubling the length of each line point, but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Never seen a zoom on a single control. I supose you could just change the font size (on the MouseWheel event) of the textbox and that would give the same effect as zooming. If you want it keyboard based, you could use the key events and look for something like [ctrl]+ or [ctrl]-